# printf in C doesn't occupy memory?

Tags: c

Does `printf` occupy memory in the stack?

```
printf("Hello world");
```

Does `"Hello world"` have a constant address?

Please help me understand.

**EDIT:**

Is the argument we are passing for the `printf` is stored in a local pointer variable.
If I use an array to store a 50 string literals it takes stack memory but if Ii use the `printf` it doesn't take memory - is what i heard. But I don't know how `printf` doesn't take memory as the array we declared.

Please help me understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your platform's calling convention and how the standard library is implemented.

For example, take the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Hello, World\n");
  return 0;
}
```

and the following command line to compile it:

```
gcc -S -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror syscall.c
```

On a 32-bit Red Hat box (i686) using gcc 2.96, we get the following machine code:

```
      1         .file   "syscall.c"
      2         .version        "01.01"
      3 gcc2_compiled.:
      4                 .section        .rodata
      5 .LC0:
      6         .string "Hello, World\n"
      7 .text
      8         .align 4
      9 .globl main
     10         .type    main,@function
     11 main:
     12         pushl   %ebp
     13         movl    %esp, %ebp
     14         subl    $8, %esp
     15         subl    $12, %esp
     16         pushl   $.LC0
     17         call    printf
     18         addl    $16, %esp
     19         movl    $0, %eax
     20         leave
     21         ret
     22 .Lfe1:
     23         .size    main,.Lfe1-main
     24         .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 2.96 20000731 (Red Hat Linux 7.2 2.96-112.7.2)"
```

Line 16 pushes the address of the string literal onto the stack, and then `printf` is called.

Here's the same code, compiled the same way, on a 64-bit SLES 10 box (x86_64) using gcc 4.1.2:

```
      1         .file   "syscall.c"
      2         .section        .rodata
      3 .LC0:
      4         .string "Hello, World"
      5         .text
      6 .globl main
      7         .type   main, @function
      8 main:
      9 .LFB2:
     10         pushq   %rbp
     11 .LCFI0:
     12         movq    %rsp, %rbp
     13 .LCFI1:
     14         movl    $.LC0, %edi
     15         call    puts
     16         movl    $0, %eax
     17         leave
     18         ret
;;
;; additional content not included
;;
```

In this case, line 14 writes the address of the string literal to a *register* (`%edi`) instead of pushing it onto the stack.  Note also that this version of gcc is smart enough to realize that since I'm passing a single argument of type `char *`, it can substitute a call to `puts`.

In either case you're creating a new stack frame when you make the call; the difference is what's in the stack frame.  On the Red Hat box, it will include the address of the string literal; on the SLES 10 box, it won't.

Answer (score 5):

String literals, which is what `"Hello world"` is, occupy memory, but not on the stack, but in a read-only static segment. Other than `read-only memory`, the rest are implementation details.

It's not necessary that identical string literals occupy the same memory (so the address is not guaranteed to be constant), but they might.

Comment: Note that although the string doesn't occupy the stack, `printf` *is* a function call, and would grow the stack accordingly.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass I doubt that. `printf` itself resides in a library, and it too has static duration.

Comment: I didn't mean that the code for `printf` was on the stack, i mean that the `call` instruction pushes the return address to the stack, and therefore the act of calling *any* non-inline function grows the stack.

Comment: @WoodrowDouglass oh, ok. That's true.

Answer (score 3):

In the C language, string literals have static *storage duration*. This means they exist (and pointers to them remain valid) for the entire duration of the program; this is the opposite of automatic local variables which are typically implemented on a call frame stack.