# adding printf increases the size of data segment

Tags: c, gcc, memory

This is what I had earlier

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

And I got this

```
rohit:~/workspace/C $ size const
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1122     276       4    1317     525 const
```

After making the below change, the data section size increases by 4.

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!!");
    return 0;
}

rohit:~/workspace/C $ size const
text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
1112     280       8    1400     578 const
```

What's the reason for this behaviour. I am using Ubuntu on x86. gcc is the compiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [printf in C doesn't occupy memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226811/printf-in-c-doesnt-occupy-memory)

Comment: Please note that your current question is missing several points to completely explain the behaviour, namely: architecture (seems x86 32bit), compiler (probably gcc), used compiler flags (probably none).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Every used string uses the memory for itself, as well as `sizeof(char*)` additional memory for a pointer to its first character.

---

You're probably on a 32bit architecture, or at least compile your program for that one. Four bytes are exactly one pointer on that architecture, so let us have a look at the assembler (`gcc -S`):

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello World!!"
```

There's a `.rodata` entry, namely `"Hello World!""` as a `.string`. That's a `const char *`, which takes four bytes on a 32bit x86 arch. If we remove that string, the `.rodata` section stays empty. The string is gone, therefore we can get rid of the pointer. Note that the pointer **itself** is not read-only. That's why you end up with an entry in `data` to begin with.

You can check this easily with `gcc -Os main.c`. The following programs should have the same `size` output (and result in almost the same assembler code):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const char * mystring = "hello world!";
    printf(mystring);
    return 0;
}
```

After all, we need the pointer for `printf` (`$.LC0`):

```
movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, %rdi
movl    $0, %eax
call    printf
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything that requires that the pointer be in writable memory - that's just how this compiler (in this configuration) happens to implement it.  Or is there something I've missed?

Comment: @TobySpeight no, that's correct. I don't have another compiler at hand to check it in other configurations, though.